# Postgres query works in SQL client but not with Hibernate

Tags: spring, postgresql, hibernate

What is wrong with the following query? It is completely working in pgadmin's sql editor, but when I added this to my programming code it's not working. I am using spring and hibernate.

```
List<Object[]> category= null;
    try{
        SQLQuery qry = session
                  .createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM (mlm_placement_details bp INNER JOIN mlm_user_reg_data t ON t.USER_ID=bp.USER_ID"
            + "WHERE (bp.USER_NAME) LIKE (:name)");
        qry.setParameter("name", "%" + userName + "%");
        qry.setMaxResults(100);

        category = qry.list();

    session.flush();
    }catch (HibernateException e) {
        logger.error(e);
        errorCloseDBSession();
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: What is the error? Please paste the trace

Comment: postgresql could not extract resultset and postgresql syntax error at end of input

Comment: Remove the parentheses after FROM `from mlm_...` not `from (mlm...`. Also: Putting column names or single values between parentheses is totally useless

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a space between your query segments. As you are concatinating: `... t.USER_ID=bp.USER_ID" + "WHERE ...`

Can you try this:

```
SQLQuery qry = session
                  .createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM mlm_placement_details bp INNER JOIN mlm_user_reg_data t ON t.USER_ID=bp.USER_ID "
            + "WHERE (bp.USER_NAME) LIKE (:name)");
```

Updated: Also noticed the unwanted opening parenthesis (Thanks to @a_horse_with_no_name)

Comment: The parenthese after the FROM also needs to be removed

Comment: parenthesis was the problem@a_horse_with_no_name